# how to create a search box filter using Aura component

Tags: aura

I created a lightning data table using Aura component in that I also added the search box filter which is above the data table. when user enters some data in search box, then result should render in that data table

Comment: use a **Search Input With Spinner** above on table,In that Search Input we need to type what ever want then press ENTER. then we need to call our apex method/JS controller logic on **onkeyup="{! c.handleKeyUp }"** to filter the data table data

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.